# How to convert from Instant to LocalDate

Tags: java-8, localdate, java.time.instant, java-time

I have an `Instant` coming from a source that should, according to the specs, be a `LocalDate`, but don't see any methods in the `LocalDate` class to convert the `Instant` to a `LocalDate`.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 191, accepted):

## Java 9+

[`LocalDate.ofInstant(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#ofInstant(java.time.Instant,java.time.ZoneId)) arrived in Java 9.

```java
Instant instant = Instant.parse("2020-01-23T00:00:00Z");
ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("America/Edmonton");
LocalDate date = LocalDate.ofInstant(instant, zone);
```

See [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/YO4edQ).

Notice the **date is 22nd rather than 23rd** as that time zone uses an offset several hours before UTC.

> 2020-01-22

## Java 8

If you are using Java 8, then you could use `ZonedDateTime`'s `toLocalDate()` method:

```java
yourInstant.atZone(yourZoneId).toLocalDate()
```

Comment: To add to this, if you want a LocalDate from "now", you can do any combination of:

Comment: yourZoneId = `ZoneOffset.UTC` for example

Comment: @Pipo I guess `yourZoneId` should be `ZoneId.systemDefault()` because we convert to user's local date

Answer (score 41):

Other answers provided the mechanics for the transformation, but I wanted to add some background on the meaning of such transformation which hopefully helps explain why it works the way it works.

---

`LocalDate` and `Instant` seem similar – they both hold date(/time) information without the time zone information. However, they have quite a different meaning.

`Instant` represents a point in time unambiguously. The representation does not explicitly contain any time zone, but implicitly it refers to the UTC time line.

`LocalDateTime` (and `LocalDate`) is ambiguous, because it represents a point in the *local* timeline, which implicitly refers to the *local* time zone.

So, in order to correctly transform an `Instant` into a `LocalDateTime` (conceptually – some of these steps are bundled together into a single operation in the implementation) you need to:
1. convert the `Instant` into a `ZonedDateTime` by applying the UTC time zone info
2. change the time zone from UTC to the *local* time zone (which implies applying the relevant time zone offset) which gives you another `ZonedDateTime` (with different time zone)
3. convert the `ZonedDateTime` into a `LocalDateTime` which makes the time zone implicit (*local*) by removing the time zone info.

Finally, you can drop the time-part of `LocalDateTime` and end up with the `LocalDate`.

Answer (score 23):

If using java 8 you can do the following

```
Instant instantOfNow = Instant.now();
LocalDate localDate 
    = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instantOfNow, ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDate();
```

Comment: This answer is not right. It should be: LocalDateTime.ofInstant(schedParams.getEnd(), ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();

Answer (score 8):

You need to ask yourself at what zone offset you want to transform it to most probably and when you know the answer to that:

```
LocalDate.ofInstant(yourInstant, yourZoneOffSet)
```

**EDIT**

just realized that this is only possible since java-9, for a pre-java9 see [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52264959/1059372)

Answer (score 1):

Complete running example, Java 8 compatible:

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;

class Scratch {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Instant now = Instant.now();
    LocalDateTime ldt = now.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime();
    System.out.println(ldt);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Instant instant = Instant.now();   
 LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.ofInstant(instant, ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

the above code worked for me.