# EpochSeconds from localdate in jdk8

Tags: java, java-8, epoch, milliseconds, java.time.instant

I am getting error ofInstant not member of LocalDate in jdk 8.

```
LocalDate.ofInstant(Instant.now(), zone).atStartOfDay(ZoneId.of("Z")).toEpochSecond
```

It's running fine in jdk11. How can the same be done in most decent manner in jdk8.

Comment: A similar problem which will solve Instant to Localdate conversion  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52264768/how-to-convert-from-instant-to-localdate

Answer (score 0):

The `LocalDate.ofInstant` method was introduced in Java 9. Here’s the version I would use no matter if using Java 8, 9 or 11:

```
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Asia/Gaza");
    long epochSecond = LocalDate.now(zone).atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC).toEpochSecond();
    System.out.println("epochSecond: " + epochSecond);
```

It gives the same result as your code if you fill in the same time zone.

If you need to convert from a given `Instant`, in Java 8 do:

```
    Instant inst = Instant.now(); // Assign your Instant value here
    long epochSecond = inst.atZone(zone)
            .toLocalDate()
            .atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC)
            .toEpochSecond();
```