# How to resolve side effect rising from LocalDate in tests (scala)?

Tags: scala, scalatest, localdate

I have a function where I convert time in millis to a `LocalDate` object:

```
def convertToLocalDateTimeViaInstant(dateToConvert: java.util.Date): java.time.LocalDate =
    dateToConvert.toInstant.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault).toLocalDate
```

And I have a unit test for this function as follows:

```
 "convertToLocalDateTimeViaInstant" should {
    "return the correct LocalDate instance" in new SAMLServiceTestEnv() {
      val timeInMillis: Long = 1349333576093L // Date is Thu Oct 04 2012 06:52:56 UTC in millis
      val someDate = new Date(timeInMillis) 
      val resultDate: LocalDate = samlServiceImpl.convertToLocalDateTimeViaInstant(someDate)
      
      resultDate.getYear mustEqual 2012
      resultDate.getMonth mustEqual java.time.Month.OCTOBER
      resultDate.getDayOfMonth mustEqual 4
    }
  }
```

When I run this test just by itself or the whole file, this test makes the correct assertions. The value `1349333576093L` corresponds to `Thu Oct 04 2012 06:52:56` UTC and `Wed Oct 03 2012 23:52:56` PST (San Francisco time).

However, when I run ALL the unit tests in the project, I observe a failure in this test. The `resultDate.getDayOfMonth mustEqual 4` assertion fails stating `4 is not equal to 3`. I'm surprised to see this as the function clearly considers UTC time when run by itself but somehow observes local time when run all together? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The standard practice is to not use `LocalDate.now()` directly. Like, at all. You have some `Clock` or `Timer` that is providing you with current time, and if you need to do any tests where time is important - you just stub this current time provider to fix time to some value. And you remove time-dependency from tests altogether. Any other approach is broken by design no matter how "pragmatic" you might want to see it.

As a matter of the fact `Clock` is a build-in  in JDK 8: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html so you don't even have to introduce a new dependency.

Comment: I'm to follow what you're saying, except I can't find a way to not do it without `now()` - my code checks where a date is close to expiry and I would need `now()` to do that comparison. How would you suggest I do this? Even if I do use `Clock` to obtain the current date/time, how do I work with a custom `LocalDate` object?

Comment: [`clock.instant()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html#instant--) returns current `Instant` (`Instant.now()`) that can be [translated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52264768/how-to-convert-from-instant-to-localdate) to `LocalDate`. So you just can write an utility that takes `Clock` obtains `Instant` and converts it to `LocalDate` and you have a flexible `LocalDate.now()` replacement that can be mocked.