# How to remove the date in Instant and only keep the date?

Tags: date, java-8

so I have two Instant from JAVA8,
`Instant time1 = Instant.parse("2020-11-03T11:35:02.510Z")`
`Instant time2 = Instant.parse("2020-10-03T07:15:22.432Z")`
and I want to remove the date information in these two instants and only keep the time(which is hour, minute, second, and millisecond with the timezone) and compare them. May I know how to do that? Appreciate your help!

Comment: An `Instant` is a moment in time, and at that moment it is never the same date everywhere on Earth. So which date do you want?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert from Instant to LocalDate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52264768/how-to-convert-from-instant-to-localdate). I believe it would have been more helpful to close this question as a duplicate than as unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Like this.  But you will need to provide an appropriate `ZoneId` and of course any special formatting for the date.  This uses LocalDate's `toString()` method.

```
Instant time1 = Instant.parse("2020-11-03T11:35:02.510Z");
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.ofInstant(time1,ZoneId.of("GMT"));
System.out.println(ld);
```

Since you have the String to parse, you could do it like this.

```
LocalDate ld1 = LocalDateTime.parse("2020-1103T11:35:02.510Z",
        DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME)
      .toLocalDate();
```

Prints

```
2020-11-03
```

Comment: thx, I have tried but my ide says cannot resolve method 'ofInstant' in 'LocalTime'.. and I import the java.time.LocalTime

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed  you said, Java8, that is in Java 9.

Comment: See my updated answer.